# Good book for MATLAB image processing functions explanation

Tags: image-processing, matlab, reference-request

What are some books that can explain what is actually going on in the MATLAB functions for image processing? Some examples would be the function `im2bw`, `imtophat`, etc.

Comment: Matlab is bundled with its own documentation that explains its internal workings to some degree. There are academic or engineering textbooks that uses many of those functions, but I haven't heard any one that explains the internal workings yet...

Comment: @A_A, Gilles, Fat32, joje

I was told from someone from stackexchangeAcademia to put this question here. According to the site description: "For practitioners of the art and science of signal, **image and video processing**".

Comment: You are right but what you ask is about **internal** details of a commercial program? Those details are either unavailable (or forbidden to share ,i.e., copyrighted) or else not much related with the mathematical theory of signals processing. On the other hand **good books on signal processing** would be a perfect question, in fact that's a perfect question which has alredy been asked and answered...